# Is there a linearly-independent set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is not the trivial set ${(0,1),(1,0)}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know that ${(0,1),(1,0)}$ is a linearly-independent set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but is it unique? Can I found another set of vectors, which is linearly-independent as well? Is there a general way to found it in $\mathbb{R}^4$, $\mathbb{R}^5$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: There are *infinitely* many [linearly independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Definition) sets of $2$ vectors in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: You seek a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)), and there are plenty.  For example, $\{(1,1),(1,-1)\}$.

Comment: Any two vectors that are not colinear form a basis of $\mathbb R^2.$

Comment: $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ always work, provided that $\frac ab\ne\frac cd$.

Comment: Or, in a more common form, provided that $ad-bc\ne0$. (The quantity $ad-bc$ is called the "determinant" of the matrix $\left[\begin{matrix}a&b\\c&d\end{matrix}\right]$, so we can write it as $\operatorname{det}\left(\left[\begin{matrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{matrix}\right]\right)\ne0$.)

Answer (score 3):

Two vectors $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ are linearly independent - and hence they spann $\mathbb R^2$ or equivalently they *form a basis of $\mathbb R^2$* if they satisfy $$α\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}+β\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{pmatrix}=0 \implies α=β=0$$ Rewrite the first part to obtain a system \begin{cases}αx_1+βy_1=0\\αx_2+βy_2=0\end{cases} The solution $α=β=0$ is obvious. But how can we exclude any other solution? This system does have other solutions (for $α,β$) and thus violates the condition for independence iff $$\det\begin{vmatrix}x_1& y_1\\x_2& y_2\end{vmatrix}=0 \iff x_1y_2-x_2y_1=0 \tag{*}$$ So, choose **any** two vectors $x,y$ that violate $(*)$ and you have a basis. For example $x=(3,4)$ and $y=(1,0)$. There are infinitely many.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Take $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$.

There are infintely many such sets.

One way to get a lot of them for $\mathbb{R}^n$ is to generate a $n$-by$n$ matrix with independent and identically distributed entries from some continuous distribution (say, standard normal). If the determinant of the matrix is non-zero, then the columns form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. This happens with very high probability.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the rows of any square matrix $A$ in which $\text{det}\neq0$ as independent vectors.

Comment: I use an IPhone right now and your comment is absolutely welcome. indeed, I meant non zero det. However, the other answer covered what I was trying to say properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any set of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $e_i\cdot e_j=0$, for $i\neq j$, we have that they are linearly independed. This can be done for any amount of dimensions there and any variety of these.